# Install 3th party app on android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I'm trying to get Salesforce installed on a Android emulator.
But it seems Google Play has been removed from any and all official emulators.

Does anyone know how i can get Salesforce or any other 3rd party app on an Android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb for it.

```
adb install <path/to/apk>
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move

Comment: But then i would need the Salesforce APK file ?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from the play store.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of sites that collect `APK`s and provide them to the world directly. Going for a quick Google surf saying "Salesforce apk latest" will give you a bunch of results. There will probably be a bunch of ads. When you finally download an APK, use the stuff @Lyra provided: Run `adb install <apk file location>`. 
And that's it. You're done!